# mockReturnValue for multiple functions from React Hook not working fine

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui

I have a React application using MaterialUI and use media query to check if isPrint and isSmallScreen and the application displays accordingly

const isPrint = useMediaQuery('print')
const isSmallScreen = useMediaQuery(theme => theme.breakpoints.down(theme.breakpoints.values.md))

Now I am trying to mock it in my jest Tests and it does not work well. This is what I tried. Should I do it differently?

```
useMediaQuery.mockReturnValue({ isSmallScreen: true, isPrint: false })
```

When I try to display in console.log it displays like this for

```
console.log(isSmallScreen, isPrint)

{ isSmallScreen: true, isPrint: true } { isSmallScreen: true, isPrint: true }
```

How should I mock it so it mocks the conditions correctly?

Comment: Unable to do 2 media at the same time.. desktop and print

Comment: `useMediaQuery` should always return a boolean. Your mock return value shouldn't be an object. Your mocking approach needs to look at the input of the function and then return the correct boolean result. I would recommend using [mockImplementation](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn) rather than `mockReturnValue`.

Comment: I tried this  so it returns false for print and true for others. Does not work

Comment: Object.defineProperty(window, 'matchMedia', {
            writable: true,
            value: jest.fn().mockImplementation(query => ({
                matches: query !== 'print',
                addListener: jest.fn(),
                removeListener: jest.fn()
            }))
        })

Comment: the above query It worked. I had accidentally included jest.mock('@mui/material/useMediaQuery') and that was forcing it to not work